Помогите с функцией на SQL (plpgsql)
Есть здание Создать и выполнить хранимую процедуру, в которой добавить новый самолет. 
План самолёта с указанием мест.
ПРОЦЕДУРА:
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_aircraft(
    p_aircode VARCHAR(3),
    p_model JSONB,
    p_range INT
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT aircraft_code FROM aircrafts_data WHERE aircraft_code = p_aircode) THEN
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Сомалет с кодом "%" уже существует!', p_aircode;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO aircrafts_data (aircraft_code, model, range)
        VALUES (p_aircode, p_model, p_range);
        RAISE NOTICE 'Самолет с кодом "%" успешно добавлен!', p_aircode;
    END IF;
END
$$

Но процедура добавляет только самолеты в таблицу aircrafts_data, но так же нужно добавить номера мест в этих самолетах для таблицы seats. Как можно это реализовать?
ДИАГРАММА БД:

ЗАПИСИ В ТАБЛИЦЕ seats:


p_range это что за параметр такой? Нужен на вход параметр с количеством мест. В самой процедуре, в цикле от 1 до N инсертить записи в таблицу seats

@SwaD p_range это расстояние которое может пролететь самолет. А если я цикл сделаю, то seat_no рандомно инсертить? Я добавил картинку записи из таблицы seats
в seat_no есть цифры и буквы

Я не знаю, это ваше задание. А так у самолета есть ряды кресел и указание, сколько кресел в 1м ряду. Либо сами придумайте рассадку, либо спросите у препода

Как можно это реализовать? Ээээ... вторым запросом, вестимо.

@Akina а если внутри этой же хранимой процедуры

Да пожалуйста. Просто не надо прибавлять текущее. Вычисляй сумму заново. Это гарантирует, что даже если вдруг в вычисления из-за каких-то внешних факторов вкралась ошибка (что само по себе маловероятно, но не невозможно), следующее изменение её исправит и перезапишет.
